# Creating a heatmap using .csv in R

Tags: r, csv, heatmap

I'm trying to figure out how to create heatmaps.

I have a csv file that I've imported with 61 observations of 58 variables, formatted as follows and have changed all na values to 0s.

```
      T1   T2   T3   T4
1 aaa 3    6    3    0
2 aab 1    8    5    0
3 abb 2    5    0    0
4 bbb 10   0    10   7
5 bbc 8    2    8    1

heat <- data.frame(read.csv("heatdata.csv", header=T))
write.csv(heat,"heat.csv",na="0")
heat <- data.frame(read.csv("heat.csv", header=T))
```

I would like to create heatmaps, both using all of the data in the data frame, as well as specifying particular columns (only T2 and T3, for example). I have tried using both heatmap and heatmap.2 but I obviously don't have my data formatted correctly and am not sure how to handle the data.

```
heatmap(heat2)
Error in heatmap(heat2) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

The NA in your matrix is causing the issue. Remove NA with some numeric value

Answer (score -1):

Assume this is your original CSV:

```
    T1   T2   T3   T4
aaa 3    6    3    NA
aab 1    8    5    NA
abb 2    5    NA   NA
bbb 10   NA   10   7
bbc 8    2    8    1
```

Then you don't need to change NA's explicitly. Without `row.names = FALSE` you are getting redundant indices on second read.

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
    T1   T2   T3   T4
aaa 3    6    3    NA
aab 1    8    5    NA
abb 2    5    NA   NA
bbb 10   NA   10   7
bbc 8    2    8    1", sep = "")

df <- read.csv("heatdata.csv", header=TRUE)

heatmap(as.matrix(df))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I am still receiving the following error: Error in heatmap(as.matrix(df)) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix

Comment: @rileycattus Can you try loading the original dataset with `row.names = FALSE` and then `dput` the resulting `data.frame`? And add this to the question, so I can see the difference with my interpretation.